# Why my cron Job does not work?

Tags: cron

Here is my cron job:

```
*/10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:99  #this is to open a port by Xvfb
*/10 * * * * python Crawler.py   #this file will use a selenium to script the data through firefox browser.
```

Currently I am using aws EC2 Ubuntu OS to run this job. If I type this command manually through the terminal, it work well. All the crawling results saved under correct directory path. But when I use cron job to run, no file is generated. And I go through /var/log/syslog to view the cron job log, it states that the cron job has already executed. SO what is the reason to cause that issue?

```
Oct 26 02:00:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6415]: (ubuntu) CMD (run_crawler)
Oct 26 02:17:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6422]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 26 03:17:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6459]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 26 04:00:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6473]: (ubuntu) CMD (run_crawler)
Oct 26 04:17:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6519]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 26 05:17:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6549]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 26 06:00:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6577]: (ubuntu) CMD (run_crawler)
Oct 26 06:17:01 ip-172-31-28-165 CRON[6763]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but those 2 commands are executed separately. The

```
*/10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:99
```

does not know about

```
*/10 * * * * python Crawler.py
```

You need to put the 1st command into the 2nd command if the "Crawler.py" needs a DISPLAY.

Besides that: it is also better to include the paths infront of both the "python" and the "Crawler.py".

I would assume it needs to be something like this ...

```
*/10 * * * * DISPLAY:99 && /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/local/Crawler.py
```

if python is in `/usr/bin/` and you script in `/usr/bin/local/`.

There are better methods though:

Use [xvfbwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xvfbwrapper). It is a independent wrapper you can use as a  context manager:

```
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
    with Xvfb() as xvfb:
         # rest of your script goes here (start/stop etc)
```

---

- This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb) on stackoverflow has some more information about using "selenium".
- Also [interesting](https://dev.e-taxonomy.eu/trac/wiki/TestingSelenium): [Seleniumhq Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Seleniumhq+Plugin)

Comment: Many Thanks, xvfbwrapper is awesome. it simplifies the task a lot.